# C# Is it possible to block a specific URL (in web browsers) on your local machine?

Tags: c#, .net, url, block

**Preferred Language:** C#

**Description:**
I would like to block a specific URL (ex: www.myurl.com/pages/page), from being opened through any web browser (or even a particular browser if that's easier).

***NOTE:**

- It needs to be a specific page on the website, not just the domain.
- I want to write an application to be able to do this... not use browser extensions or an anti virus.

**What I've researched/tried:**

- Unfortunately you cannot block specific pages with Windows Hosts file, as it only blocks domains (and I tried it myself).
- Other than editing the hosts file, I've not found any other ways to go about this.

Detailed steps/explanations would be great.

Comment: I think it's going to require use of a proxy server. And then you're at the mercy of the user changing the proxy settings.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a router with Access Restrictions and dns forwarder blocker, so all dns requests pass through the router. I suggest using a dd-wrt router or a mikrotik routerboard. Assuming your network do not allow any proxy.

Comment: DNS restrictions aren't going to work for per-page blocking.